# How do I combine 6 categorical (yes/no) variables into 1 umbrella categorical variable (yes/no)

Tags: r, categorical-data

I have a dataset like this following example:

```
bleed  breathing  ascites   spleen  Hepato
Yes      Yes         No       Yes    No
No       Yes         No       Yes    No
No       No          Yes      Yes    No
```

I need to create a new umbrella variable that describes the 5 categorical variables. As long as a patient has a "Yes" (complication) in ANY of the 5 categorical variables that he/she should get a "Yes" in the new umbrella variable (i.e. they belong to the new category). Only if the person has a "No" in ALL of the 5 categories should they get a "No" in the new umbrella category.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `rowSums` on a logical `matrix` to get the sum on each TRUE/FALSE outcome.  Create a logical vector `> 0`, add 1 to it so that TRUE/FALSE, converts to 2/1 and this can be used as index to replace with a vector of new values ("No", "Yes")

```
df1$umbrella <- c("No", "Yes")[(rowSums(df1 == "Yes") > 0) + 1]
df1$umbrella
#[1] "Yes" "Yes" "Yes"
```

---

Or another option is `Reduce` with `lapply`

```
df1$umbrella <- c("No", "Yes")[(Reduce(`|`, lapply(df1, `==`, "Yes"))) + 1]
```

Or with `apply`

```
c("No", "Yes")[1 + apply(df1 == "Yes", 1, FUN = any)]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(bleed = c("Yes", "No", "No"), breathing = c("Yes", 
"Yes", "No"), ascites = c("No", "No", "Yes"), spleen = c("Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes"), Hepato = c("No", "No", "No")), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. I am a newbie to R, so I need some clarification from you. If I want to use these codes of yours, by using the variable name of my dataset. It should look like this, right? -

    dataset$umbrella = c("No", "Yes")[1 + apply(dataset$bleed == "Yes", 1, FUN = any)]
    dataset$umbrella = c("No", "Yes")[1 + apply(dataset$ascites == "Yes", 1, FUN = any)]

Comment: @ShakilAhmedShaon Here, `df1`is the object name.  If you dataset name is `mtcars`, you should replace 'df1' with `mtcars` i.e. you may have read your data like `yourdata <- read.csv('file.csv')` then `yourdata` is the object name

Comment: @ShakilAhmedShaon if `dataset` is the object name, yes it is the code.   But you have changed my code buy extracting a column and then use `apply`, that won't work

Comment: @ShakilAhmedShaon. IN your case, it would be `apply(dataset == "Yes", 1, FUN = any)`. If you extract a column, it is a vector and `apply` is for matrix or data.frame

Comment: I used the following commands: (r = name of my dataset)

`r$compli = c("No", "Yes")[apply(r$Bleeding == "Yes", 1, FUN = any)]`

I am getting the following error messages: 

`Error in apply(r$Bleeding == "Yes", 1, FUN = any) : `
`dim(X) must have a positive length`

Comment: @ShakilAhmedShaon I already commented regarding that code previously that you are extracting a column and then using `apply` which won't work..  According to `?apply` `X- an array, including a matrix.` here the `r$Bleeding` is a vector